# How do I build an application with a docker image?

Tags: linux, windows, docker, compilation, cross-platform

I have a docker image that I am trying to use to cross-compile an application for Windows. However, whenever I enter the docker image, it does not show my filesystem, so I cannot reach my source code.

How do I build with a docker image? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand right, the image contains your development environment, and you only need a way for the container to see your code on the host machine at runtime. The answer is in the question then.

Just start your container with the source directory mounted:

```
docker run --rm -it -v%my_src_dir%:/workspace centos:6.6 /bin/sh
```

Then inside the container, you `cd /workspace` to continue development.